# pandas not finding csv file

Tags: python, pandas, csv, path

reading a csv file won't work and gives me the error "FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory". The csv file exists and I put it in the same folder as the .py file

```
import pandas as pd

test_df = pd.read_csv("fake_or_real_news.csv")
```

the error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'fake_or_real_news.csv'
```

Comment: Use the absolute path of the file, eg.: `/home/you/documents/fake_or_real_news.csv` instead. By using just the filename, python expects it to be in the current working directory. You can figure out what that is with `import os; print(os.getcwd())`

Comment: can you do a tree command of your folder structure ?

Answer (score 0):

Check where you are running the script from. You are probably not in the right folder (working directory)

Answer (score 0):

you can use absolute path as

`import os`

`print(os.path.abspath("fake_or_real_news.csv"))`